# Javascript form validation: how to force focus to remain on 'incorrect' field?

Tags: javascript

I can't believe that I can't find the answer to this question but I really have searched and can't find it! honest!

anyway - here is the question: I am trying to create a validation function for a form that will not permit the user to proceed to the next form field if the field doesn't validate. 
I just want the 'incorrect' field to have focus until it is 'correct'.

because this is for a JS class I cannot use jQuery or any other framework.

here is one of the HTML fields:

```
<li>Number 1:<input class="field2" type="text" id="star1" onchange="validateAndDraw(this.value);"></li>
```

and here is a truncated version of the JS function:

```
function validateAndDraw(theValue) {                
  if (isNaN(theValue)) {
    alert("no good");
  } else {
      [do stuff here]
  }
}
```

I have tried using 'this.focus();' and 'this.parentNode.focus();' but no joy.

I am sure the answer is ridiculously simple, but I can't seem to find it.

thanks,
bennett

Comment: I thought that using `onchange` and similar event attributes has been deprecated in favor of binding event handlers via JavaScript (unobtrusively) ... if that is for a JS class, then maybe this could be one of the lessons. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('star1').focus();`

Using `this` inside your function will refer back to the function.

Alternatively, you could pass the object in the `onclick` event:

```
<input class="field2" type="text" id="star1" onchange="validateAndDraw(this);">
```

so the function could look like

```
function validateAndDraw(obj) {
  alert(obj.value);
}
```

Comment: Rather than refer bakc to the "function" did you mean that "this" refers back to the tag?

Answer (score 3):

Try sending the object reference to the function instead of the value.

So in your input event:

```
validateAndDraw(this);
```

And change your function to:

```
function validateAndDraw(input) {                
  if (isNaN(input.value)) {
    alert("no good");
    input.focus();
  } else {
      [do stuff here]
  }
}
```

As a side, I would suggest looking into [Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `focus()` in the `blur` event.

Also, `this` in your function refers to the global context, not the element.
(It  only refers to the element inside the *inline* handler; you are making an ordinary function call from there)
You should change your function to accept the element as a parameter (which you can pass as `this` insidethe inline handler)

Comment: @SLaks Shouldn't he be passing just `value` and not `this.value`. That should work, right?

Comment: @SLaks Yea, I got it. It seems that everybody here got that solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass in the element?

```
function validateAndDraw(theElement) {
    var theValue = theElement.value;
    if (isNaN(theValue)) {
        alert("no good");
        theElement.focus()
      } else {
          [do stuff here]
    } 
}
```

Comment: beaten like a fluffy egg white.

Answer (score 0):

**Send** as trigger

There are for each loop function for check input in form.

If there are input[x].value = "", so alert and focus in it, next input and next alert

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <form onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">

      Name:     <input type="text"     name="name"><br />
      E-mail:   <input type="text"     name="email"><br />
      Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />     

      <input type="submit" value="Send">

    </form>

    <script >

      function validateForm(input) {

        for (x in input) {

          if (input[x].value == "") {

            alert(input[x].name + " must be filled out");
            input[x].focus();

            return false;
           
          }   

        }

      } 

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer and don't just post code.